# Pygame - surface fade in/out

Tags: python, sdl, pygame

I'm writing an application that shows a list of messages coming up on a PyGame window; to make things prettier, I decided to add a nice fade in/out effect to the text.

Problem is: SDL only allows per-pixel or per-surface alpha, not both. So I wrote a function that recalculates the pixel alphas based on the wanted "layer" opacity, but it's of course very, very, very slow (even on a core i7 @2.7GHz, it's dropping to ~10FPS):

```
def apply_alpha(surface, alpha):
    for x in xrange(surface.get_width()):
        for y in xrange(surface.get_height()):
            color = surface.get_at((x, y))
            color.a = int(color.a * alpha)
            surface.set_at((x, y), color)
    return surface
```

Full example here: https://gist.github.com/rshk/5072173 (not the real application, just a relevant example)

Is there any way to speed up things? I see it's possible to directly access the underlying buffer, that avoids instantiation of `Color` objects, but it seems to be even slower to update the alphas that way, calling the `BufferProxy.write()` method..

Maybe something using hardware acceleration would help? I think the ideal here would be to apply the alpha while blitting the surface onto the background, but I'm not very expert in this kind of things..

**note:** changing the text color is not a chance, as the background might not be always black..

Comment: Why don't you make another surface? Then you'd get access to the per-surface alpha...

Comment: I tried, but it seems to have no effect..

Comment: ..you were right, I tried again and, in this example, it works! I suspect there is some issue with some flags in the "real world" application.. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As this might serve as future reference for somebody, I did as suggested by @Xymostech: create another surface with the same size of the rendered text and apply the alpha on that surface, using `.set_alpha()`.

Updated version here: https://gist.github.com/rshk/5072375

Comment: Good thought. Honestly I wouldn't think text would require this since it doesn't really have an alpha channel of its own, so you can just set_alpha it, but this looks very useful.